# Select unique value from table has null columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `detail_product` table.

the `product_id`, `category_id`, `color_id` and `size_id` are foreign key for the table `product`, `category`, `color` and `size`respectively

```
id | product_id | category_id | color_id | size_id
---------------------------------------------------
1  |     1      |      1      |   null   |   null
2  |     1      |      2      |   null   |   null
3  |     1      |     null    |    1     |   null
4  |     1      |     null    |   null   |    2
5  |     2      |      2      |   null   |   null
6  |     2      |     null    |    2     |   null
7  |     3      |      1      |   null   |   null
8  |     3      |      2      |   null   |   null
9  |     3      |     null    |    1     |   null
10 |     3      |     null    |    2     |   null
```

How I can select the `product` which satisfies conditions. I got stuck when select because of the `null` value in these columns. For example, I want to select all `products` which belong to `category 1` and `category 2` and have `color` is 1 then which sql statement should write?
(In that example my expected value is that `product_id` return 1 and 3).

Does anyway to skip these `null` columns or some statements to solve my problem?

I have tried this but it not work:

```
SELECT detail_product.product_id 
FROM  `detail_product` 
WHERE  detail_product.category_id = 1 
AND    detail_product.category_id = 2 
AND    detail_product.color_id = 1
```

Comment: @tcadidot0 sorry my bad, I just have edited it

Comment: *which belong to category 1,2* Does this means "1 or 2" or "both 1 and 2"?

Comment: @Akina it means for both 1 and 2, I also have an example to illustrate my idea

Comment: Ok, after seeing Akina's answer I understand what you're trying to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT product_id 
FROM detail_product
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(1, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)) -- category_id=1 must exist
   AND FIND_IN_SET(2, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)) -- category_id=2 must exist
   AND FIND_IN_SET(1, GROUP_CONCAT(color_id))    -- color_id=1 must exist
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_id , GROUP_CONCAT(category_id) catid, GROUP_CONCAT(color_id) colid
FROM detail_product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING (1 IN (catid) OR 2 IN (catid)) 
       AND 1 IN (colid) ;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r5q7YZVgnERKDPfnK6zNZN/1

Comment: your answer is working. However, if I remove color condition then, the query will return all 3 products

Comment: That's depending on your condition @TùngNguyễn .. we can't possibly give you an answer to fulfill condition that wasn't part of the question/example. However, I believe Akina's answer is more fitting for you to accept. I actually posted this because I already made it so it's a waste if I didn't "save" it somewhere. It's a learning process for me too :)